# Django app deployment on shared hosting

Tags: python, django

I am trying to deploy a django app on hostgator shared hosting. I followed the hostgator django installation wiki and i deployed my app. The issue is that i am getting a 500 error internal page when entering the site url in the browser. I contacted the support team but could not provide enough info on troubleshooting the error `Premature end of script headers: fcgi`.This was the error found on the server error log.

I am installed django 1.9.5 on the server and from the django documentation it does not support fastcgi.

So my question 500 error be caused by the reason that i am running django 1.9.5 on the server and it does not support fastcgi. if so do i need to install lower version of django to support the fastcgi supported by hostgator shared hosting

First i thought the error was caused by my .htaccess file but it has no issue from the what i heard from support team.

Any Leads to how i can get the app up and running will be appreciated. This is my first time with django app deployment. Thank you in advance

Comment: Premature end of script headers Maybe : Your first line declaration is missing(which app run this code #! /usr/bin/python ?) or printed any data on your app script(enable cgitb on flask) and `How to register your app ?` `chmod a+x your_app.py`. Ask your service provider(Because you want access   server loopback)

Comment: @dsgdfg what do you mean by printed any data on your app script? I also changed the execution permissions for manage.py but none seems to be working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know this is a while as to when i asked the question. I finally fixed this by changing the hosts. I went for Digital Oceans (created a new droplet) which supports wsgi. I deployed the app using gunicorn (application server) and nginx (proxy server).

It is not a good idea to deploy a Django app on shared hosting as you will be limited especially installing the required packages.

Answer (score 1):

Many hostings today that support python use Phusion Passenger and I have been able to deploy Django on it successfully. Before I share the procedure, let me mention that I faced a lot of problems in doing this and now I have the solution to all of them. I have already written a step by step guide on my blog [here](https://blog.umersoftwares.com/2019/09/django-shared-hosting.html) to deploy a Django app on shared hosting.

- Start a new python app in cpanel. Specify the url where you want the app to be and the folder where you want to put the contents of the app. Set the **Application startup file** to `passenger_wsgi.py` and the **Application entry point** to `application`.
- Copy the command to enter the virtual environment and run it via online terminal in CPanel or SSH.
- Install version 2.1 of Django (latest 2.2 will not work) `pip install django==2.1`
- Upload your django project to the folder you specified while setting up the app. There will be a **passenger_wsgi.py** file in that folder. Edit it and enter the following code: (replace **myapp** with your application name)

`from myapp.wsgi import application`

- Edit the **settings.py** file and add the url of your appp to the **ALLOWED_HOSTS** list.
- [Set up the MySql database](https://blog.umersoftwares.com/2019/09/django-shared-hosting.html#9-set-up-the-database)
- [Configure the path for static files](https://blog.umersoftwares.com/2019/09/django-shared-hosting.html#10-set-up-static-files) in the **settings.py** and run `python manage.py collectstatic`
- Again go to **Setup python app** in cpanel and restart the app.

Answer (score 0):

As you say, Django 1.9 does not support FastCGI.

You could try using Django 1.8, which is a long term support release and does still support FastCGI.

Or you could switch to a different host that supports deploying Django 1.9 with wsgi.

Comment: i downgraded django to 1.8.4 but still getting the 500 error page.  Also this is what i get in the error log  [Fri Apr 15 07:07:48 2016] [warn] [client 192.185.1.20] (104)Connection reset by peer: mod_fcgid: error reading data from FastCGI server
[Fri Apr 15 07:07:48 2016] [error] [client 192.185.1.20] Premature end of script headers: index.fcgi . Any leads from there?

Comment: CGI : `HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\n\n` +Content headers +Content . `500 error` a `from x import y` (where X ?), print something before headers(Wrong cgi-header/headers), syntax error, wrong first line(which app need to run code (` #! /usr/bin/python`)),

Comment: Sorry, I can't help with deploying Django on fastcgi. Hope you manage to get it working.

Comment: @dsgdfg my python header path is correct. used the one i get from the command "which python". Otherwise i am not sure what to do next

Comment: Used more connection on same port(fastcgi used x and your app need used y port), you can't listen a port with more than one app !